# The affiliation and footnote superscripts overlap in the authblk package

Tags: footnotes, superscripts, authblk

I'm using the `authblk` package with the following code:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}
\title{The Title}

\author[1]{Alice}
\author[2]{Bob\thanks{Corresponding author}} % a footnote indicating Bob is the corresponding author
\affil[1]{University A}
\affil[2]{University B}

\renewcommand\Authfont{\large}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\small}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

The output is like this:

[image]

Notice that the affiliation superscript `2` and the footnote superscript `*` overlapped, which is unreadable.

Can someone suggest what should I do to fix this, more specifically, getting the below expected output?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example of code, starting from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`?

Comment: @egreg I edited the code

Comment: It seems to be a defect with the class you are using, where did you get that class from, it is not known to my TeX Live. BTW: it works just fine if I use the `article` class instead.

Comment: I don't think you should use `authblk` together with `sig-alternate`, which has its own method for typesetting the article's title elements.

Comment: @daleif It's ACM SIG Proceedings Template (http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates), where I used the `LaTeX2e - Tighter Alternate style`

Comment: I agree with @egreg if this is an article for ACM then use their interface (even if you perhaps do not like the layout). It is a big annoyance to journal/proceeding editors when authors attempt to edit the journal/proceeding layout. (of course there are exceptions from this rule)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to eliminate the `thanks` asteric, and keep it on the box (i.e., change `\author[2]{Bob...}` to `\author[2*]{Bob...}`).

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
 {\def\@makefnmark}
 {\def\@makefnmark{}\def\useless@macro}
 {}{}
\makeatother
```